# How to access a const inside a function in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-script-setup

I'm using Laravel/Inertia/Vue3, I get the user object, and then I want to use it inside other function, but its always undefined.

```html
<script setup>
// imports...

const props = defineProps({
    // props...
})

const user = computed(() => usePage().props.value.user);

const click = () => {
  alert(`${user.name} clicked`);
}
</script>
```

If I try to access the `user` object in the HTML vía the handlebars, it works as intended, but I can't use it in the click function. Of course I could assign a `const user` inside the function with the value `usePage().props...` but this looks quite ugly, and there must be another way.

Of course, I'm pretty new to Vue.

EDIT #####

I'm refering to this when I say it looks ugly:

```html
<script setup>
// imports...

const props = defineProps({
    // props...
})

const user = computed(() => usePage().props.value.user);

const click = () => {
    const user = usePage().props.value.user;
    alert(`${user.name} clicked`);
}
</script>
```

There must be a better and correct way

Comment: Btw it's unknown what usePage is but it's generally incorrect to use composable functions in nested functions, it needs to be called in setup body

Comment: I got it from here: https://inertiajs.com/shared-data in the second paragraph

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`computed()` returns a [`ref`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref), so your click handler needs to unwrap the value via the `ref`'s `value` prop:

```html
<script setup>
const user = computed(() => usePage().props.value.user);

const click = () => {
  //alert(`${user.name} clicked`); ❌
  alert(`${user.value.name} clicked`); ✅
}
</script>
```

Alternatively, you can avoid the unwrapping with the [Reactivity Transform](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-transform.html) in `<script setup>` (i.e., `$computed()` in this case):

```html
<script setup>
//const user = computed(() => usePage().props.value.user);
const user = $computed(() => usePage().props.value.user);

const click = () => {
  alert(`${user.name} clicked`);
}
</script>
```